# Is there a way to get water into the nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Just exploring the nether, found my first nether fortress, and lots of netherwart.  Wanting to start brewing potions in the nether fortress, but getting a source of water is problematic.  Is there a way to get water into the nether in vanilla minecraft (i.e. no mods)?  I'd like an unlimited water source if possible.

Comment: I don´t really know but have you jsut tried carrying it in buckets through the portal? ^^

Comment: Yes, but when I drop it on the ground (I just tried netherrack, have not tried netherbrick) it just fizzles.

Comment: It's much more reasonable to dig up some soulsand, pick the nether wart and start farming it at your base, on the surface.

Comment: In Bedrock: Apparently there's a bug that allows Water to generate in the Nether, and Netherrack is replaced by stone (no ores)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The easiest way is to build a portal nearby, travel to the normal world, fill your glass vials with water there and bring those back to the Nether. You can fill as many vials as you can fit in your inventory and it won't take much time out of your brewing schedule.

You could also keep water in the Nether in a cauldron, but as that only holds 3 vials worth, it's slower than simply bringing the water to the Nether in vials.

Comment: If you fill your inventory with buckets of water, on the other hand, you can carry 3xInventorySize vials worth of water. Toss them all in a chest and refill your cauldron while each set of water vials is turning into a base potion.

Answer (score 19):

In versions of Minecraft before the current 1.0.0 release, you could use the Silk Touch enchantment to get Ice blocks, and break them in the Nether to produce water source blocks. However, this was patched, and they won't create water in the Nether anymore.

The only way to place water in the Nether, currently, is to place a [Cauldron](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cauldron) and fill it with water. Sadly, it isn't as good as an infinite source, as it can only fill 3 Glass Bottles before needing to be refilled, but it's the only option for brewing in the Nether at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Create two ender chests, keep one and one world and the other in the nether fill it with buckets of water you can keep up to 27 buckets in an ender chest it's the easiest way to get water in the nether.

Comment: This question has already been answered a long while ago. And you still haven't answered how to *place* water in the Nether.

Comment: The question may be old, but this does propose a solution to the asker's actual problem. And it hasn't even been poste yet.

Comment: Using a shulker box would let you do the same, without taking up the ender chest space, but filling the ender chest with shulker boxes full of water buckets would let you have 729 buckets or 2187 bottles.

Answer (score 2):

You really can't have a source of water legitimately in the nether, you can only put it from a bucket to a cauldron in vanilla.

You would need to use mods such as TooManyItems to spawn pure water that's not in a bucket. It looks like vertically flowing water in the GUI. This is the only way to get placeable water in the nether. It won't sizzle, but be placed instead and flow.

One way to kind of keep the vanilla feel would be to make a bucket, find a water source, and "scoop up" the water by just giving yourself a water block and having the bucket empty.

Comment: Pure water as an item was removed entirely in 1.7

Answer (score 2):

Only raw water can be placed in the Nether. If your single-player world has cheats enabled or you are an op on a multiplayer server, use `/give <your name> <8 or 9> <amount>` to get that. 8 is source water, whereas 9 is stationary water.

Comment: So this means it IS possible?

Comment: This no longer works as of 1.7

Answer (score -3):

Ice Blocks can still be used in the Nether to create water, in 1.1. These can be obtained by mining them with a tool that has the silk touch enchantment.

Comment: Iron pick ax with silk touch does not permit ice block mining.

Comment: This no longer works in the current version

Answer (score -4):

you can't place water in the nether but you can get water in the nether by placing ice blocks  and melting them.

Comment: This was a bug and no longer works since being fixed in later versions.

Comment: It was patched as of Minecraft 1.3.1

Answer (score -4):

Do /give [player] 79. Then place it somewhere that the will melt.

Comment: Way to bump a question answered since two years. Why don't you check the [unanswered questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/unanswered) page instead?

Comment: This answer is also wrong.  Ice no longer melts in the nether, it just sublimates.

Comment: Also, it doesn't work in single player without cheats activated.

Comment: If you have cheats, you could just give yourself 8 or 9 to get pure water to place in the Nether.